# I want the Loop to stop if the value taucher.xPosition is equal or below 0

Tags: python-3.x, class, keyboard, zero

If i continue pressing the left arrow key, I want the value taucher.xPosition not to be below Zero. It should just stop right there. Now the Output when i keep pressing the right arrow key looks like this:

10
x:  9
x:  8
x:  7
x:  6
x:  5
x:  4
x:  3
x:  2
x:  1
x:  0
x:  -1
x:  -2
x:  -3

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OxilF.png)

This is the code:

```
while True:
    inputLeft = False
    while inputLeft == False:
        if keyboard.is_pressed('right arrow'):
            taucher.moveright()
            print("x: ", taucher.xPosition)
            time.sleep(1)
            inputLeft = True
```

I tied to do a for Loop that counts from 500 to 0, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with the code is that there is currently no check for the value of `taucher.xPosition`. It allows to `moveright()` every time the right arrow key is touched. To change this behavior, we can add a `Boolean` condition to check the value of `taucher.xPosition` **and** if the `right arrow` was pressed:

```
while True:
    inputLeft = False
    while inputLeft == False:
        if taucher.xPosition > 0 and keyboard.is_pressed('right arrow'):
            taucher.moveright()
            print("x: ", taucher.xPosition)
            time.sleep(1)
            inputLeft = True
```